# Is there any restrictions on save NSDictionary to file

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I want to use the following method to save `NSDictionary`

```
+ (void)writeDicToFile:(NSDictionary *)dic fileName:(NSString *)fileName
{
NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
[dic writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```

But for some dictionary it works and for some complex dictionary it doesn't work.

help me!

Comment: the objects in dictionary have to conform to [<NSCoding> protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) so they can be (de)serialized

Comment: Thank you! I know where the error is now.

Comment: And I look for ways how to implement that.

Comment: No problem. What you have to do is implement `encodeWithCoder:` and `initWithCoder:` methods - and tell the compiler that object conforms to this procol by adding `<NSCoder>` to the class definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for `NSDictionary` to be successfully saved all the objects it holds have to conform to [NSCoding protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

In short that means that you have to implement

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
```

and

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
```

for all your custom classes.

A nice tutorial is here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1914/nscoding-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-save-your-app-data

**EDIT:**

Once you have written you `NSCoder` methods you can save data like this:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
[archiver encodeObject:self];
[archiver finishEncoding];
[data writeToFile:file atomically:YES];
```

And init the object from file like this:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:file];
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
self = [unarchiver decodeObject];
[unarchiver finishDecoding];
```

You did mention having problems with json object: the thing about json object is that first you have to check its type: it can be a `NSDictionary` or a `NSArray` - depending on the input and format.

Common problem occours when you get an array with only one element - dictionary you are looking for. This happens if your dictionary `{...}` json representation is embedded within `[]`.

Comment: it still doesn't work. I have implement encodeWithCoder: and initWithCoder: methods. help!

Comment: NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:jsonObject];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

Comment: Can you post a bit more on how you generate this jsonObject? With json parsers there is a "problem" that you usually don't know in advance if the result will be dicitonary or an array. And please post your implementation of the two methods.

Comment: thank you for you editing, it's done now. At first I still try to use the  `NSDictionary writeToFile:filePath atomically:` method. Thanks a lot @rokjarc

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says that :

```
- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag
```

> This method recursively validates that all the contained objects are
>   property list objects (instances of NSData, NSDate, NSNumber,
>   NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary) before writing out the file, and
>   returns NO if all the objects are not property list objects, since the
>   resultant file would not be a valid property list.

What objects are you puttin in your dictionnary ?
Put property list objects in your dictionary, then there are no reason that it does not work.

you should also see the return value for the method. ( YES or NO).