# Other ways to save an NSMutableArray in Xcode

Tags: ios, save, nsuserdefaults, property-list

I receive an error when i try to save my NSMutableArray to the NSUserDefaults and I have read enough to understand that because my array is like this:

```
CustomClass *customObject;
NSMutableArray *mutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:customObject,nil];
```

Because mutArray has a non-property-list object (customObject) it can't be saved neither onto the NSUserDefaults nor in a .plist file, so I need another way to save it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to save to nsuserdefaults for custom class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000220/best-way-to-save-to-nsuserdefaults-for-custom-class)

Answer (score 2):

Make `CustomClass` implement the `< NSCoding >` protocol, then archive the instance to data. Now you can add the data to the array / plist. Or save it to disk.

Answer (score 0):

When saving a mutable array (or dictionary) its 'mutability' shouldn't confuse you. You would save it as you would save its non-mutable sibling.

In order to make it mutable again when loading it you should load it and call `mutableCopy` on the loaded object. I know this is not your question at the moment but i have a feeling it will be soon.

To successfully save an array or dictionary all of the objects (their classes...) that container hold must conform to the `<NSCoding>` protocol. More on this [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20742899/653513).